# Facebook PHP API getReachEstimate

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am quite a beginner and trying to learn to apply some things in Facebook PHP SDK, but there are some things poorly explained in the documentation.

My goal is to get number of users who say are interested in both "socker" and "football".

I think a function [getReachEstimate($array, $array)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reachestimate/v2.3) does exactly that, my approach would be.

```
use FacebookAds\Object\ReachEstimate;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\ReachEstimateFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;

$account = new AdAccount($account_id);
$reachEstimate = $account->getReachEstimate($SOME_ARRAY, $SOME_ARRAY2));
```

I looked in the source of SDK and this function takes two arrays, but it is nowhere explained what are these arrays must look like. If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: The two parameters ($fields and $params) look like they take in the targeting spec and search terms respectively. Your terms "soccer" and "football" would probably therefore go in the second array.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter seems irreverent to me. But I'm not sure. Will update the answer when I find. Meanwhile here's how to do it:

Suppose following are your parameters:

```
$params = [
  'targeting_spec' => ['geo_locations' => ['countries' => ['US']]]
];
$fields = [];
```

Then call it in the following way:

```
$adAccount = new AdAccount($adAccountId);
$adAccount->getReachEstimate($fields, $params)->getData();
```

So, put your [Targeting Spec](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs/v2.3) in `$params` and the calls

Hope this helps!